# how to fix undefined this keyword variable when calling from function

Tags: javascript, global-variables, chatbot

I would like to run this code but its giving me output of undefined in second console log instead of Oracle as I'm trying to call it from var retrieve name with reference to global var and this keyword.

```
this.name = "Oracle";
var website = {
name: "Java",
getName: function () {
return this.name;
   },
 };

console.log(website.getName()); // Java

var retrieveName = website.getName; //
console.log(retrieveName()); // Oracle but its printing undefined

var boundGetName = retrieveName.bind(website);
console.log(boundGetName()); // Java
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your findings, the code logs "Java", "Oracle" and "Java" in sloppy mode, and fires an error in strict mode. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work-and-when-should-it-be-used

Answer (score 0):

[output received][1]

I was running the code in Node.js that's why it seems to provide error on global var access. Now I made to run in Sloppy mode then ALL CLEARED..

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It is not the same, if you declare function, or value.

```
var website = {
name: "Java",
getName: function () {
return this.name;
   },
 };

console.log(website.getName()); // Java

var retrieveName = website.getName(); //
console.log(retrieveName); // Java

website.name='Oracle';

var boundGetName = website.getName.bind(website);
console.log(boundGetName()); // Oracle
```

Set **this.name** outside of an object is incorrect using of [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).